# Iphone UITabbarController

Tags: iphone, sdk, navigation, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a iPad application where i am using more than one Views. The thing is i want to display the TabbarController page while clicking on Button that is on main page. I am able to call the TabBarController directly from delegate method like adding TabBarController to MainWindow in Inspect window. But the thing is i am asking for users to first login to application and after successful loging, Dashboard appears where i have Buttons. Clicking on button i am displaying Tableview in one Tab bar and in another Tabbar Add to list form.

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: Was there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

What I can get from your post is that you want to have the user log in before the Tab Bar appears with your views.

If that's the case, then you want to set your login view as the main view of the window, and then after they log in set the view to be the view of the Tab Bar.

Comment: You are Correct @Undeadlegion. I want to display main View of the window first and then Tab Bar form.